The Azure DevOps parameters radio button is only showing for a maximum of three values
As I noticed in parameters in Azure DevOps, only a radio button is shown for a minimum of three values. If the value is more than three, then it shows a dropdown option.
3 value log
Does anyone know why this is happening and what the fix is if I want to have a radio button for five values?
more than 3 value logs

I don't think there's any way to control this, its just by design. If its 3 items or less then its a radio button, if its more than 3 then its a drop down.

Currently, Azure DevOps will automatically select the display type based on the number of parameter values.
When the number of values ​​is greater than 3, drop-down list will be displayed. Otherwise, it will show as radio button.
The reason for this situation could be that the developers want to keep the Run Pipeline UI clean.
If the interface displays too many radio buttons, it could be confusing and cause some options to not stand out.
I'm afraid that there is no such method can control the type of parameter values ​​displayed(Radio button or Dropdown list) for the time being.
I can fully understand your requirement. It would be useful if Azure DevOps can provide a field to customize the type of parameter value displayed. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature
